# Как создать DynamicMethod из IL-кода?

Tags: c#, winforms, компиляция

мне необходимо создать DynamicMethod по IL-коду следующего метода:

```
public int test(string v1, int v2)
{
    return (int)call(new object[]{ v1, v2 });
}
```

где

```
public object call(object[] args)
{
    // что-то возвращающее int
}
```

Я переписал код из ildasm в ILGenerator.Emit, но при выполнении сгенерированного делегата появляется ошибка недопустимого кода MSIL. Помогите, пожалуйста, создать корректные вызовы ILGenerator.Emit для генерации метода, либо пришлите ссылки на литературу по этому. Заранее благодарю!

```
Type[] arg_types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) };
            var dn = new DynamicMethod("myMethod", typeof(int), arg_types);
            var il = dn.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(int));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Form1).GetMethod("call"));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, typeof(int));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var del = dn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, int, int>));
            del.DynamicInvoke("test",77);
```

Comment: Так вы бы привели бы код из ildasm. Может, что-то неправильно переписали

Comment: .method public hidebysig instance int32  test(string v1,
                                              int32 v2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       36 (0x24)
  .maxstack  5
  .locals init ([0] int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0003:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Object
  IL_0008:  dup
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000a:  ldarg.1
  IL_000b:  stelem.ref
  IL_000c:  dup
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000e:  ldarg.2
  IL_000f:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0014:  stelem.ref

Comment: IL_0015:  call       instance object WindowsFormsApp1.Form1::'call'(object[])
  IL_001a:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_001f:  stloc.0
  IL_0020:  br.s       IL_0022
  IL_0022:  ldloc.0
  IL_0023:  ret
} // end of method Form1::test

Как я понял, где написано [mscorlib]System.Object, 2 параметр Emit будет Type, где call, там MethodInfo, у меня вопросы со строкой IL_0020, непонятно, что передавать.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/Rk5HL9joFRTUIg

Comment: тут очень неудобно читать код в комментариях. Вы как автор можете дополнить сам вопрос, оформив код как код. Можете так же показать код с emit-ами, ведь именно в нем искать ошибку

Comment: Я изменил вопрос, скриншот il-кода выше.

Comment: `DeclareLocal(typeof(int))` не хватает для объявления лок переменной, тк есть опкод, к ней обращающийся.

Comment: Или просто убери строки 001f и 0022, можно и 0020. Они не нужны. И попробуй. Правда меня ещё смущает 3 аргумента: в сигнатуре их два, а в коде работа с тремя (ldarg.0, ldarg.1 и ldarg.2). Но я с телефона в уме не сложу, почему так оно работает.

Comment: Я добавил 
dn.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.In, "v1");
dn.DefineParameter(2, ParameterAttributes.In, "v2");
убрал 001f, 0022, 0020, но все равно "адресат вызова создал исключение".

Comment: надо сделать что-то одно: либо добавить параметры, либо убрать строки - одновременно этого делать не стоит

Comment: Ни тот, ни другой вариант не подействовал. Предполагаю, что в 0020 не хватает аргумента.

Comment: да удали этот `br.s`, он там не нужен вообще

Comment: Уже, только ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Что еще может быть не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямая работа с Reflection.Emit обычно используется в особых случаях, когда нужно сгенерировать сложный многострочный метод. Для однострочного метода, который только вызывает другой метод, можно использовать более простое высокоуровневое средство - деревья выражений. При их использовании не нужно задумываться об отдельных инструкциях и корректности IL. Вот пример, также для более простого случая, когда метод call - статический:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object call(object[] args)
        {
            //...
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "v1");
            ParameterExpression param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "v2");

            NewArrayExpression expr_arr = Expression.NewArrayInit(
                typeof(object),
                Expression.Convert(param1,typeof(object)),
                Expression.Convert(param2, typeof(object))
                );

            MethodCallExpression call_expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("call"), expr_arr);
            UnaryExpression conv_expr = Expression.Convert(call_expr, typeof(int));

            var f_expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, int, int>>(conv_expr, param1,param2);
            Func<string, int, int> f = f_expr.Compile();
            int res = f("test", 77);
        }
    }  
}
```

При этом деревья выражений внутри также используют Reflection.Emit и динамические методы. Тип времени выполнения метода f.Method будет `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod+RTDynamicMethod`, он также будет создан в специальной изолированной системной сборке и может быть выгружен сборщиком мусора, когда он больше не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ полностью решил мою задачу.

Comment: как еще можно в call передать второй строковой аргумент?

Comment: @Antinet использовать другую перегрузку метода, принимающую 2 аргумента (или массив аргументов): https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: Да, только какой класс, унаследованный от Expression, мне использовать?

Comment: @Antinet Любой класс, который возвращает строку, в том и смысл деревьев выражений. Это может быть ConstantExpression, содержащий константную строку, ParameterExpression, указывающий на строковую переменную, MethodCallExpression с вызовом метода, возвращающего строку. Если вам трудно составить выражение для сложной строки кода, вы можете для начала объявить его как лямбду (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/#creating-expression-trees-from-lambda-expressions), а затем посмотреть отладчиком, что внутри получившегося выражения.

Comment: Благодарю, мне помог Expression.Constant.

Comment: И еще вопрос, как в строке Expression.Convert(call_expr, typeof(int)); изменить возвращаемое значение на Void (Action<>)?

Comment: @Antinet Если метод не возвращает ничего, Convert не нужен. В Expression.Lambda в этом случае можно передать напрямую Expression.Call

Comment: А если метод что-то возвращает, но делегат должен иметь возврат void?

Comment: @Antinet Попробуйте сами на практике реализовать то, о чем вы спрашиваете, тогда все станет ясно. Если делегат возвращает void, то и метод ничего возвращать не должен - корневое выражение может тогда возвращать любой тип, он будет просто игнорироваться. Явное приведение к void не требуется. Как я уже сказал, если составление выражений вручную представляет трудности, начните с лямбд.

Comment: Делегат возвращает void, однако вызываемый им метод возвращает object. Попытка убрать Expression.Convert не меняет исключения.

Comment: @Antinet Какого исключения? Вроде работает: https://gist.github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/4bdaa799637b1d41dde8d1ce2d362ae8

Comment: Действительно, я вчера где-то ошибся в коде.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ лежит рядом. Все комментарии выше верны, но вы создаете динамический метод `DynamicMethod`, который не принадлежит ни одному экземпляру класса, к которому принадлежат call() и test(). Это не плохо и не хорошо: ваш метод просто висит в воздухе. То есть ваш emit создает примерно следующее:

```
class Test{
    public static int test(string v1, int v2)
    { 
        return (int)call(new object[]{ v1, v2 });
    }    
}

class Call{
    public object call(object[] args)
    {
        // что-то возвращающее int
    }
}
```

Такое не скомпилируется

Чтобы обратиться к методу call экземпляра вашего класса необходимо либо загрузить  (либо передать) в ваш метод экземпляр класса Call (в вашем случае, это, видимо, `Form1`), либо создать динамический метод call подобно тому, как вы создали test, либо сделать call статическим. Последний способ наиболее простой:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var a = new MyClass().test("d", 5);

        Console.WriteLine(a);

        Type[] arg_types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) };
        var dn = new DynamicMethod("myMethod", typeof(int), arg_types, typeof(MyClass));
        var il = dn.GetILGenerator();                        
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(int));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("call"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, typeof(int));            
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var del = dn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, int, int>));
        var r = del.DynamicInvoke("test", 77);

        Console.WriteLine(r);



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int test(string v1, int v2)
    {
        var a = call(new object[] { v1, v2 });
        return (int)a;
    }

    public static object call(object[] args)
    {
        // что-то возвращающее int
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что я использовал перегрузку DynamicMethod с указанием типа. Согласно документации - это тип, к открытым методам которого динамический метод будет иметь доступ. (скорее всего, `myMethod` будет динамически добавлен как статический метод этого типа. Но это не точно. Довольно любопытная штука).

Comment: Я вам предельно благодарен, все работает!

Comment: Скажите, а что не так здесь?
il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, typeof(string[]));

Comment: @Antinet, откуда вы эту строку взяли?

Comment: Ниоткуда, я меняю возвращаемое значение.

Comment: @Antinet, ну во-первых, для того. чтобы изменить возвращаемое значение, необходимо изменить сигнатуру функции, а во-вторых, `string[]` - уже объект (ссылочный тип), и он не нуждается ни в упаковке, ни в распаковке

Comment: Все сверху изменено, а что вписать в возвращаемое значение Unbox_Any? Туда подходят только скалярные типы.

Comment: @Antinet , для `string[]` вообще не нужно ничего писать. Просто удалите строчку с unbox_any из кода. Упаковка/распаковка нужна только для значимых типов как `int`, `char`, `double` итп. Любой массив - уже объект и в упаковке не нуждается